# Microsoft Word keeps reversing my unchecking of "Disable OpenType Font Formatting Features"

Tags: microsoft-word, fonts, opentype

I open a document, I go to File > Options > Advanced > Compatibility options and uncheck "Disable OpenType Font Formatting Features", and click OK. I save the document, close the document, open it again, go to the same place and it is checked again.

Does anyone know why this is happening? Thanks.

Comment: What version of Word?

Comment: @Mokubai - Microsoft Word 2016 MSO (16.0.8326.2076) 32-bit